# Can't find method in $scope after angular $compile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

sorry if it's a trivial question, I'm new to AngularJS and front-end development.

I'm trying to create a modal with bootbox, as bellow:
In Service:

```
function _modalData(){
    let element = "<div onclick=\"saveSelection(true);\"><b>Save</b></div>" /* etc*/
    return $compile(element)(v_scope);
}

function openModal(){
    bootbox.dialog({
        animate: false,
        message: _modalData(),
        onEscape: true,
        backdrop: true,
        scrollable: true
    });
}
```

In Controller:

```
$scope.saveSelection= function (keepData) {
    ...
}
```

I put the $scope in the variable v_scope, and already used it a lot in other modals inside the same service, so I think he is ok, but when I'm trying to click on the div, there's a problem saying "can't find saveSelection", does anyone know what can be giving this error?

---

### new code:

I change the `onclick` to `ng-click` and add the function in the scope after defining the element

```
let element = "<div ng-click=\"saveSelection(true);\"><b>Save</b></div>";

v_scope.test = function () {...}
```

I've solved it, don't know why but now it's working.. if anyone can explain why would be nice

Comment: Use the `ng-click` directive instead of `onclick`.

Comment: it stopped giving me an error, but the click doesn't call the function

Comment: Why do people still inject $scope into their controllers? Google started recommending using controllerAs syntax about 5 years ago. Go read up on components and controllerAs syntax and stop injecting $scope. You will write much better Angular apps.

Answer (score 0):

`onClick` is a javascript Event handler which can't call a angular's controller function. To call controller's function you have to use `ng-click` which is angular directive to handle click event in angular.

`onClick` is used to call javascript native function where `ng-click` is used to call angular function.